# SVG Animation - Animating SVG groups

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, svg

I want to achieve a conveyor belt animation on an SVG element i.e. the blocks on the conveyor belt need to move along with the belt in a particular direction.

A better view of what i want to achieve:
[GIF](http://gph.is/2o6IcV0)

The SVG image has separate groups for separate blocks that need to be moved along a line (belt). The svg can be found [here](http://codepen.io/binarytrance/pen/NpBdPE?editors=1010)

I tried using jquery animate to move them at an angle like so:

```
$(function() {
    var dist = 130;
    var angle = -48;
    var x = Math.cos(angle*Math.PI/180) * dist;
    var y = Math.sin(angle*Math.PI/180) * dist;
    // $(".st93").animate({'left': '+='+x+'px', 'top': '+='+y+'px'}, 1000);
  $(".st93").animate({"transform": "translateX(+=" +x+ "px)"}, {"transform": "translateY(+=" +y+ "px)"}, 1000);
})
```

which didn't work.

and then i tried using CSS only transforms like so:

```
#Square_1 {
  position: relative;
  animation-name: move;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@keyframes move {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
    //transform: translateX( -400px, 10px);
  }
  10% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  90% {
    opacity:1;
    transform: translate( 100px, -60px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity:0;
  } 
}
```

which took me closer to what I wanted but still isn't showing the desired effect. the blocks start abruptly forming at their respective starting position instead of a continuously flowing from the start of the belt which seems far from natural.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Translating it is what you need to be doing. "Which didn't work" doesn't show very much effort. What, specifically doesn't work about it? What part are you stuck on?

Comment: @ZachSaucier updated question and pen

Comment: @snow You said, *" the blocks start abruptly forming at their respective starting position instead of a continuous flow along the belt which seems far from natural."* Try changing  `animation-iteration-count: infinite;` to `animation-iteration-count: 1;`

Comment: @zer00ne that would move a block only once and totally stop it after. I want an effect such that when one block reaches the end of the belt, it fades in at the very start of the the belt which would keep the belt consistently populated with blocks giving the illusion of an actual conveyor belt

Comment: @snow comment at the parts you are having trouble with. You can't expect anyone to actually spend time analyzing every bit of code.

Comment: @zer00ne i have now removed code that's not required for the particular animation in the pen. Also included a link to a gif

Comment: The trick is to have the translation animation separate from the opacity animation. So you have something like `0% { transform: startingPos; opacity: 0; } 10%, 90% { opacity: 1; } 100% { transform: endingPos; opacity: 0; }`

Comment: @snow I'll take a look after work.

Comment: @snow I can only give you advice because a solid solution involves too much time and it's specific code may be of no use to others. Having said that, I was going to post a solution using the SVG element [`<animate>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animate). I'll `+1` to increase your chances of attracting the attention of someone better than I.

Comment: hey @zer00ne i made the animation work.. I'll post the solution here in sometime. Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: @snow I'm glad you resolved the issue, and I'm looking forward to see what you did. I imagine that it wasn't easy.